# Combine two arrays sum the duplicate Values and divide them by the number of duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code that combines the 2 arrays, and sums the same values.

so the print will be

```
Array
(
    [1] => 30
    [2] => 30
    [3] => 40
)
```

but the desired result is

```
Array
(
    [1] => 15
    [2] => 30
    [3] => 40
)
```

since `(10+20)/2` is what I am looking for.

How to edit the code to achieve this?

```
$ids = Array(1, 1, 2, 3);
$quants = Array(10, 20, 30, 40);

$a = array_unique($ids);
$a = array_combine($a, array_fill(0, count($a), 0));

foreach($ids as $k=>$v) {
  $a[$v] += $quants[$k];
}

print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this may help

```
    $ids = Array(1, 1, 2, 3);
    $quants = Array(10, 20, 30, 40);

    $a = array_unique($ids);
    $a = array_combine($a, array_fill(0, count($a), 0));

    $x = array_unique($ids);

    $count_map = [];

    foreach ($x as $temp) {
      $count_map[$temp] = 0;
    }

    foreach($ids as $k=>$v) {
      $count_map[$v] = $count_map[$v] + 1;
      $a[$v] += $quants[$k];
      $a[$v] = $a[$v]/$count_map[$v];
    }

    print_r($a);
```

Comment: Thank you, it does the job. One question, from your experience does this take a long time to be executed having in mind that the 2 arrays have only 10 items each ?

Comment: No not at all, 2 arrays and that too having 10 items each, it will take some mili seconds max, don't worry about execution in this case

Comment: thanks again. it will allow me to accept this solution in 5 minutes

Comment: Can't you use `array_count_values` to create `$count_map`?

Comment: @Barmar I don't use array_count_values that often, so while coding this it didn't clicked my mind.